# generated jhipster project is giving error

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

i have generated new jhipster project with following setting. trying to login into admin screen, I am getting error 
`Failed to sign in! Please check your credentials and try again.`
command line display following error.

`[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/profile-info from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common
_system_errors)`

I am using generator-jhipster@4.6.1.

with jhipster configuration

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.ae"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.6.1",
    "baseName": "ex",
    "packageName": "com.ae",
    "packageFolder": "com/ae",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "replaced-by-jhipster-info",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

Environment and Tools

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

git version 2.7.4

node: v6.11.1

npm: 5.0.3

yeoman: 2.0.0

yarn: 0.27.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

This means that webpack-dev-server could not connect to your java app to proxy all API calls, so you probably ran only `yarn start` and forgot to run java app with `mvnw`. See [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/development/)